# What is the strength of “if $c≥0$ then $[0,c] = c·[0,1]$” in constructive math (w.r.t., LPO, WLPO, LLPO, etc.)?

Tags: lo.logic, constructive-mathematics, reverse-math

**Context:** This question is about constructive mathematics, such as in the internal logic of a topos with natural numbers object, or in [IZF](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/axioms-CZF-IZF.html).  (I wish to avoid the axiom of countable choice if possible, but a partial answer in, say, Bishop-style constructive mathematics — which has dependent choice — is still interesting.) ❧ By “real numbers” (and the set $\mathbb{R}$ of them) I mean the *Dedekind* reals, as defined in A. S. Troelstra & D. van Dalen, *Constructivism in Mathematics* (1988), chapter 5, section 5, or in P. Johnstone, *Sketches of an Elephant* (2002), section D.4.7.

The following principles are standard at least under the assumption of countable choice (in its absence, the subscript $\mathbb{R}$ is used to distinguish them from analogous principles about binary sequences):

- $\mathbf{LPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the statement that for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $a<0$ or $a=0$ or $a>0$.
- $\mathbf{WLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the statement that for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $a\lessdot 0$ or $a=0$ or $a\gtrdot 0$.
- $\mathbf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the statement that for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $a\leq 0$ or $a\geq 0$.

— where “$a\lessdot 0$” is defined as “$\neg(a\geq 0)$” (where $a\geq 0$ is itself equivalent to $\neg(a<0)$) and analogously for “$a\gtrdot 0$”.  (Note that $a>0$ implies $a\gtrdot 0$ and that the latter implies $a\geq 0$, so $\mathbf{LPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ implies $\mathbf{WLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and the latter implies $\mathbf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$.)

**Definition:** Let me further call $\mathbf{CPO}$ (for “Convexity Principle of Omniscience”, my terminology) the statement that if $c\geq 0$ then $[0,c] = c·[0,1]$, or equivalently:

> if $0\leq x\leq c$ then there is $0\leq t\leq 1$ such that $x = c·t$

(it's sufficient to demand that there is $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x = c·t$ because then $t' = 0\sqcup(t\sqcap 1)$ will satisfy $0\leq t'\leq 1$ and still $x = c\cdot t'$, where $\sqcap$ and $\sqcup$ denote the binary inf and sup operations on $\mathbb{R}$).

**The question:** has the above-defined $\mathbf{CPO}$ been studied in relation to $\mathbf{LPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$, $\mathbf{WLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mathbf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and similar principles?  Does it have a standard name?  Is it equivalent to one of the three?

---

To motivate my question, let me show that:

- $\mathbf{LPO}_{\mathbb{R}} \Rightarrow \mathbf{CPO}$: We want to show that if $0\leq x\leq c$ then there is $0\leq t\leq 1$ such that $x = c·t$.  By $\mathbf{LPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ we can assume that $c<0$ or $c=0$ or $c>0$.  The first case trivially contradicts $c\geq 0$.  In the second, we have $x=0$, so $t=0$ works.  In the third case, $c$ is invertible (as $\mathbb{R}$ is a Heyting field) so we can let $t = x/c$ which works (and by a remark made above we [can] have $0\leq t\leq 1$).
- $\mathbf{CPO} \Rightarrow \mathbf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$: If $a\in\mathbb{R}$, applying $\mathbf{CPO}$ to $x := \frac{1}{2}(a + c)$ where $c := |a|$, which satisfies $0\leq x\leq c$, we see that¹ there is $-1\leq u\leq 1$ (namely $2t-1$ where $x=c\cdot t$) such that $a = u·|a|$.  Now by a fundamental property of the Dedekind reals (Troelstra & van Dalen, *op. cit.*, chapter 5, theorem 5.12(iii)(h)), we have either $u<1$ or $u>-1$.  But $u<1$ contradicts $a>0$ (because then $|a|=a$ is invertible so necessarily $u=1$), in other words, $u<1$ implies $a\leq 0$, and similarly $u>-1$ implies $a\geq 0$.  So we have $a\leq 0$ or $a\geq 0$, as claimed.

1. [**Corrected**] The statement that for if $|a|\leq c$ then there is $u\in[-1,1]$ such that $a = c\cdot u$ is, in fact, clearly equivalent to $\mathbf{CPO}$ and maybe more satisfactory.

I have not been able to prove the converse of one of these two implications, nor to relate $\mathbf{CPO}$ with $\mathbf{WLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$, hence my question.

I also didn't find the statement I called $\mathbf{CPO}$ above in [Hannes Diener's long text on “Constructive Reverse Mathematics”](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.05495), though of course I may have missed it, but I'd be surprised if it hasn't been considered (and named) before.

Comment: It seems closer in strength to LLPO than LPO.

Comment: Could you formulate a binary sequence form of CPO under DC? Many independence results about constructive recursive mathematics use Cauchy reals or binary sequences, so formulating binary sequence version of CPO would be helpful to work on independence results.

Comment: Quick observation: the "uniform" form of CPO ($\exists f\,\forall x\,x = f(x)|x|$, for example) gives a discontinuous function, so that seemingly stronger form implies at least WLPO.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I proved that his original form is equivalent to LLPO (assuming DC), so your alternative is much stronger

Comment: Countable Choice + LLPO is enough to imply IVT. Use Countable Choice to define a function $P : \mathbb Q \to \{0,1\}$ so that $P(q) = 1$ implies $f(q) \geq 0$, and $P(q) = 0$ implies $f(q) \leq 0$. Then using $P$, it is possible to do interval bisection without further application of Countable Choice or LLPO.

Comment: Your "alternative form" of CPO is in fact equivalent to LLPO, unconditionally. I haven't been able to show that your "alternative" is equivalent to your original. In fact, I think we have evidence that your original is strictly stronger.

Comment: The correction doesn't seem necessary to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais The statement “for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ there is $u\in[-1,1]$ such that $a=u·|a|$”, which I had initially written in my footnote 1, is equivalent to LLPO (to prove that it is implied by it, just use $u=1$ if $a≥0$ and $u=-1$ if $a≤0$; to see that it implies it, distinguish $u<1$ and $u>-1$ as in the text of the question). If it turns out to be equivalent to CPO, this answers the question. But I don't know how to do it, and I believe not (and at any rate, that's not what I had wanted to write).

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure to what extend an analysis via Weihrauch reducibility (see [1] for an introduction/survey) is of interest to you, but I'll put it forth anyway. The fact that we are finicky about how often a principle is used here might make it easier to translate constructions into a choice-less context than eg arguments in Ishihara/Diener-style constructive reverse mathematics.

In this context, I called $\mathrm{CPO}$ *robust division* in [2], as it essentially lets us divide by a real number, if it might be $0$. The principle was relevant in the context of analyzing the existence of Nash equilibria in finite two player games. More results are in [3].

Key takeaways: $\mathrm{LLPO}$ is Weihrauch reducible to $\mathrm{CPO}$, but $\mathrm{CPO}$ is not Weihrauch reducible to any finite number of $\mathrm{LLPO}$-applications. $\mathrm{CPO}$ is strictly below both $\mathrm{LPO}$ and $\mathrm{IVT}$ (called "convex choice" $\mathrm{XC}_{[0,1]}$ in much of the Weihrauch reducibility literature).

A Weihrauch equivalent formulation over binary sequences would be:
$$\forall p \in \mathbf{2}^\omega \ \exists q \in 2^\omega \ \ (p \neq 0^\omega) \rightarrow \exists k \in \mathbb{N} \ p = 0^k1q$$

[1] V.Brattka, G.Gherardi & A.Pauly: Weihrauch Complexity in Computable Analysis (http://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03202)

[2] A.Pauly: "How non-computable is finding Nash equilibria", JUCS 2010 (https://doi.org/10.3217/jucs-016-18-2686)

[3] T.Kihara & A.Pauly: "Dividing by Zero - How Bad Is It, Really?", MFCS 2016, (https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2016/6470/)

Comment: The title of that second paper is quite provocative!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Weihrauch reducibility, but this seems quite interesting: can you suggest a starting point for someone already familiar with (not-too-fancy) constructive math in general, and with Turing-reducibility if this helps?

Comment: I'm wondering whether Weihrauch reducibility can help produce a model of choiceless constructivism where CPO is true and IVT is not. Dependent Choice can be restricted to only Turing computable things, and therefore not be applicable to anything that needs CPO to be true.

Comment: Arno's result implies that in the internal logic of a topos one cannot derive CPO. If we could, then we could derive LLPO in the Kleene-Vesley topos. It also implies that there is no instance reduction in constructive mathematics from CPO to finitely many instance of LLPO. If there were, we woudl have one in the Kleene-Vesley topos, contradicting Arno's result. So if there is a constructive proof that LLPO implies it CPO, it must be a very unusual one.

Comment: @Arno, can you prove a stronger result that CPO is not reducible to any parameterization of LLPO (in analogy to Section 2.5 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.01734.pdf)? (A special case often considered in the Weihrauch land is parametrization by $\mathbb{N}$, which gives countably many instances – but in general we can relace $\mathbb{N}$  by and represented space or an assembly.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer What about IVT vs LLPO? Do you know whether they've been separated?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Parameterizing LLPO by $\mathbb{N}$ already gives us WKL, which can do CPO and IVT. For all the separations, the restrictions to "finitely many uses" is definitely needed (but the finitely many uses could be sequential in principle).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I've added the link to an introduction/survey paper on Weihrauch reducibility.

Comment: @Arno: Excellent, this means we should constructively expect that compactness of $[0,1]$ yields CPO. (Note that in TTE compactness of $[0,1]$ is “free” – an artifact of working in a particular realizability model.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer What you said doesn't make sense. TTE does not imply LLPO, so how can it imply CPO? TTE is conservative and computable, and LLPO is non-constructive and uncomputable.

Comment: @wlad: Please be explicit about what you are referring to. Did I claim that LLPO is valid in TTE? Where?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I don't know what “TTE” is, but your above comments appear to be saying that ①compactness of $[0,1]$ holds in TTE (“for free”), and that you expect ②compactness of $[0,1]$ to imply $\mathbf{CPO}$; now since ③$\mathbf{CPO}$ implies $\mathbf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ as pointed out in the question, putting together ①, ② and ③ demands that $\mathbf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ hold in TTE. But probably ② is not what you meant to say.

Comment: (In the topos of sheaves over $\mathbb{R}$, compactness of $[0,1]$ holds as I understand the latter statement, but $\mathbf{CPO}$ or even $\mathbf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ do not hold. So probably the sentence “we should constructively expect that compactness of $[0,1]$ yields CPO” wasn't intended to mean ②.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: thanks for the explanation. Yes, I got my implications reversed, sorry. The shortest explanation of TTE is that it is the relative realizability topos $\mathsf{RT}(\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}, (\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N})_{\mathsf{eff}})$, also known as the Kleene-Vesley topos.

Comment: @AndrejBauer There appears to be a non-realisability direction to the problem of showing that $LLPO \not\implies CPO$. The statement CPO has the shape $\forall\exists$, and I suspect that this can be given a topological meaning that validates LLPO but not CPO. Namely, (taking $T$ to be a topological space) the semantic meaning of $(\forall x \in T) (\exists y \in T) \phi(x,y)$ can be that there exists a *finite* closed covering of $T$, for which each closed set can be open-covered, and for each set in the resulting set covering we can attach a continuous function sending $x$ to $y$.

Comment: This proposal validates everything that's been said so far, and appears to answer Gro Tsen's question. In particular, letting $T$ be the compact subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ for which $0 \leq y \leq x$ and $x \leq 1$, we can show that LLPO is true, CPO is not, and $\varepsilon$-CPO is. While it's not rigorous, it seems very promising to me.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer

$$\mathbf{IVT} \implies \mathbf{CPO} \implies \mathbf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}},$$
where $\mathbf{IVT}$ means Intermediate Value Theorem. Why is this true?

**Proposition**: $\mathbf{IVT} \implies \mathbf{CPO}$

*Proof*. Assume $0 \leq x \leq c$. Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R, t \mapsto c\cdot t - x$. We can see that $f(0) \leq 0 \leq f(1)$, so the conditions to apply the IVT hold. We then get that there is a $t \in [0,1]$ such that $f(t)=0$. Rearranging gives $c\cdot t = x$ as desired. Q.E.D.

### Improvement assuming <strike>Dependent</strike> Countable Choice

$$\mathbf{IVT} \iff \mathbf{CPO} \iff \mathbf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$$

Why? It follows from the following proposition.

**Proposition**: *Assuming Countable Choice, $\mathbf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ $\implies$ $\mathbf{IVT}$*

*Proof*. Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function satisfying $f(0)\leq0\leq f(1)$. By LLPO, for every rational number $q$ in $[0,1]$, we have $f(q) \geq 0$ or $f(q) \leq 0$. By Countable Choice we obtain a function $P : \mathbb Q \cap [0,1] \to \{0,1\}$ so that $P(q) = 1$ implies $f(q) \geq 0$, and $P(q) = 0$ implies $f(q) \leq 0$. Then using $P$, it is possible to do interval bisection without further application of Countable Choice or LLPO. Q.E.D

### Possibility of improvement not assuming Countable Choice?

I'm not sure much is known about what LLPO can do (any version) without Countable Choice. At the moment, $\mathbf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is known to be enough to prove that $\mathbb C$ [is closed under square roots](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353435/every-complex-number-has-a-square-root-via-llpo-without-weak-countable-choice), which (I believe) is enough to imply the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. While there is a constructive proof of FToA by Countable Choice (which can be improved to assume much less; see [Richman -
The fundamental theorem of algebra: a constructive development without choice](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.2000.196.213)) there cannot be an unconditional proof.

Also, if you define:

- $\varepsilon\text-\mathbf{IVT}$ to mean the weakened version of IVT which finds an interval of length $\varepsilon$ containing the root
- $\varepsilon\text-\mathbf{CPO}$ to mean the weakened version of CPO which finds an interval of length $\varepsilon$ containing $t$, given $x$ and $c$

Then we have $\varepsilon\text-\mathbf{IVT} \iff \varepsilon\text-\mathbf{CPO} \iff \mathbf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ without any choice.

Why? Observe that while applying choice countably many times is not allowed, it is always allowed to use it finitely many times using induction. It follows that $\mathbf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}} \implies \varepsilon\text-\mathbf{IVT}$ because the interval bisection can be carried out for any finite number of iterations, unconditionally.

Comment: Just to be sure, what you call $ε\mathbf{CPO}$ is the statement that: “for all $0≤x≤c$ there exist $0 ≤ t_1 ≤ t_2 ≤ 1$ with $t_2-t_1≤ ε$ such that $c·t_1 ≤ x ≤ c·t_2$”, is this correct?

Comment: There is a paper by Michael Rathjen and Ray-Ming Chen about LLPO in the absence of choice (see google).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Yes, that's right.

Comment: @SamSanders Link?

Comment: The article [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436519/what-is-the-strength-of-if-c≥0-then-0-c-c-0-1-in-constructive-math#comment1124974_436522) by @SamSanders:  [Rathjen and Chen - Lifschitz realizability for intuitionistic Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00153-012-0299-2).